# Combine multiple photos on android before uploading it on server?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to select/take photos from gallery/camera one by one then combine and save it as one for uploading to server like [instagram](http://www.guidingtech.com/13979/combine-multiple-photos-android-instagram/) do.

[image]

Lead me to do that friends.

Expected output image sample

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout of the type you wish to combine images.

For example, in case of above picture, a layout having 3 ImageViews, with required alignment, needs to be inflated.

Once you create the view, you can convert it into bitmap and convert it to Base64 and save it.

Steps:

Convert View to Bitmap

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Compress Bitmap to Base64

```
public static String encodeBitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap, int compress) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(compressBitmap(bitmap, compress), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

To render, decode Bitmap from Base64 and set to ImageView

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromBase64(String encoded) {
  byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
  return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}
```